# How long is a version of OSX supported for security updates?

Tags: macos, security, updates

How long does Apple normally support versions of OSX with security updates. What was the last OSX version to drop support for security updates? Where would I find this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently Apple supplies security updates for the current OS version and one previous version.  The supported OS versions are Snow Leopard and Lion at this time.  Leopard security updates stopped when Lion was released.

Answer (score 0):

General information about Apple Product Security [here](https://ssl.apple.com/support/security/)

The latest Apple security updates [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1222)